# AWS bring your own IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, ipv4, amazon-elastic-ip

I am a newbie to AWS. I understand there is a feature to move our own IP addresses onto AWS. So, any existing IP based restrictions don't have to change. I have a need for a new service to be deployed onto AWS (corporate account). And this new service needs just a few IP addresses to work.

I am unsure if we will be able move just a few IP addresses onto AWS. Can anyone advise? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [User guide for Bring Your Own IP Addresses (BYOIP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html) states:

> You can bring part or all of your public IPv4 address range from your on-premises network to your AWS account.

So, yes you can bring just a subset of your IP adresses to AWS. As long as the requirements listed in the documentation apply. Of particular interest might be the following limitations:

> The most specific address range that you can specify is /24.

and

> You can bring 5 address ranges per region to your AWS account.

Comment: Does `most specific address range` being a `/24` mean, we cant just get 1-2 IP addresses?

Answer (score 6):

Note that the address block assigned to your organisation must be [**Provider Independent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider-independent_address_space) or similarly portable allocation. It's not very common for even mid-size companies to have such addresses!

If your network is connected to *multiple upstream ISPs*, you've got an *AS number* and do *BGP routing* chances are you've got a *portable address block*. If you don't know what the previous sentence talks about and you've got no dedicated network team to ask you most likely don't have a PA block and you won't be able to transfer your addresses to AWS.

If you want to post the IP address you want to transfer across we can check it out and tell you if it's portable or not.

Comment: thanks. My network team confirmed that our company have limited RIPE space. And so byo-ip is not an option.